# How do I install swarm plot from seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have installed seaborn, however when I try calling `catplot` or `swarm plot` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'swarm plot'
```

any ideas as to why this is?

Answer (score 1):

You need seaborn version 0.9.0 to build a catplot or swarmplot. You can install that version using

```html
conda install -c conda-forge seaborn
```

for Anaconda

or

```html
pip3 install seaborn==0.9.0
```

which installs the package for your default python (in my case it was python 2.7)